# The Most Fitting NoSQL DB for a Decentralized Hub-and-Spoke System

Tags: database, nosql, distributed-system

We are building a distributed system that has an Hub-and-Spoke topology: central office and remote sites which are connected to the central office, in low-bandwidth (~10Mbps) WAN connection.

The system is managing data which could be updated at any site, and should also be replicated across the whole system.

The system should support working when disconnected from the network. When the network re-connects, data should be synchronized again.

We are considering using a NoSQL DB for managing our data. However we are a bit overwhelmed by the many different alternatives.

We'd love to hear suggestions about fitting solutions.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of data are you talking about?  Is it already modeled in some way?

I haven't heard of people using NoSQL systems as a replacement for site-decentralized RDBMS scenarios which you would normally look at something like replication for.  Some are probably better suited to this than others - e.g. [MongoDB](http://facility9.com/2010/11/09/comparing-mongodb-and-sql-server-replication).  Of course, the major RDBMS vendors all have their flavors of replication.  In many cases, site replication is handled with master-slave, with the site being master and central office being slave, so that remote operation can run without connection.

Comment: From what I understand NoSQL DBs were built from the groud-up to support distributed scenarios and deployment, unlike RDBMS were replication were added as an after-thought.

Comment: Our data can relatively easily be modeled as documents. The relations are sparse, and could be avoided.

Comment: @Omer Mor But the distribution is for a different reason, for load distribution, not offline execution.

Comment: @Omer Mor Have a look at CouchDB.  I would post a question with more detail about the data model and usage scenarios and with a list of proposed platforms and see if people have pros and cons for the systems to match your requirements.

Comment: @Omer Mor - A big problem is that nosql is too broad an area.  For instance, if you were to select Amazon/Google/Microsoft or some other hosted NoSql key-value store or similar cluster hosted yourself, that's not distributed in the sense you need, since you cannot operated disconnected from that "central" service.  So you're not distributed in the way you need.

Comment: I'm not referring to Cloud services, which as you mentioned, does not support disconnected operation. I'm talking more of "traditional" (if there's such thing) NoSQL DBs like CouchDB, MongoDB, Cassandra, HBase/Hadoop, RavenDB, ...